# Optimise react code to load data from multiple sources simultaneously rather than sequentially

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have 2 tabs on the page which shows visualisations generated from different data sources. Both visualisations needed multiple queries in the background to fetch the data before rendering them, so it takes some time for each tab to load individually. Currently, `componentDidMount` looks like below:

```
componentDidMount(){
   this.loadDataA();
   this.loadDataB();
}
```

Although it works, it won't start loading data for B until loading data for A is completed. If I reverse the order in the `componentDidMount` like this:

```
componentDidMount(){
   this.loadDataB();
   this.loadDataA();
}
```

then it loads data for B first and then A.

Is there a way that I can load both data simultaneously?

(I am fairly new to react, so please let me know if I am missing anything)

**EDIT 1**
Below are the load data functions:

```
async loadDataA(){
    const { queries } = this.state;
    queries.forEach((query) => {
      a_query({query}).then(result => this.handleAResult(result));
    });
  }

async loadDataB(){
    const { scopes, queries } = this.state;

     queries.forEach(query => {
       scopes.forEach(scope => {
        b_query({scope, query}).then(result => this.handleBResult(result));
     });
   });
 }
```

**EDIT 2**
The sequence of execution when `console.log` was added (thanks @TKoL), when A is called first and then B:

[image: Starting A and then B] [image: Finishes A async but B looks sequentially, probably it got resolved when waiting for A to finish]

**Note:** If you need to know any other part of the code, please ask.

Comment: if `loadDataA` and `loadDataB` are both loading data asyncronously, they will already do it at the same time the way you've written it. If the data isn't getting loaded asyncronously, then there's no way to do them at the same time

Comment: So I guess the question is, what are you loading the data from and how?

Comment: Yes, the data is loaded for both asynchronously. The data is loaded from different sources without overlap. Still, depending on the position of functions it executes sequentially. Also, I have observed that if I `console.log` in both functions, then it prints them immediately. But the loading of data for later function doesn't start until the first one is completed. Am I missing anything here?

Comment: How do you know the request for `B` data doesn't start until `A` is complete? instead of it just finishing after?

Comment: Without seeing the specific code that loads the data, it's hard to say

Comment: added `loadData` code for both functions.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to make `loadDataA` and `loadDataB` asynchronous, using promises: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Here's an example using the `async` syntactic sugar:

```
const loadDataA = async () => {
     // Actual load logic goes here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Reading everything so far it seems like `b_query` is finished after `a_query` or vice versa depending on the calling order. So either they have logic that cause sequencing or the server-side itself sequences the requests (yes there are sever features which do that).

**Edit 1**

A third possibility is that whichever endpoint you're calling finishes first and so the response is sent back faster triggering the `.then` before the second call is finished (thanks @TKoL).

Comment: There's a third option you didn't mention: it's totally possible that, for completely normal and expected reasons, whichever requests you call first are also finishing first. I believe he's interpreting that coincidence as "B requests are waiting for A requests to finish", when really it's just "I called B requests a little later, and they finished a little later"

Comment: That's exactly is not the case, so in real-time B queries take more time to load than the A queries. So if you have a sequence like A and then B, then this theory has a stand, but when you have B and then A at that time it won't even start rendering A values until all B values are not done. I am thinking it might because of the `New Relic` application I am using to get the data. But I am still investigating and will update here if I found the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

So, you have your load code:

```
async loadDataA(){
    const { queries } = this.state;
    queries.forEach((query) => {
      a_query({query}).then(result => this.handleAResult(result));
    });
  }

async loadDataB(){
    const { scopes, queries } = this.state;

     queries.forEach(query => {
       scopes.forEach(scope => {
        b_query({scope, query}).then(result => this.handleBResult(result));
     });
   });
 }
```

and you call it like this:

```
this.loadDataA();
this.loadDataB();
```

Now, it's my theory that it's actually working perfectly fine. The way your code SHOULD work hypothetically, without changing it at all, is that it called a_query_1, then a_query_2, then a_query...z, and then it does all the b_queries, but without waiting for it to get the results of the a_queries back

So I would recommend adding these console.log lines to verify:

```
async loadDataA(){
    const { queries } = this.state;
    queries.forEach((query, index) => {
      console.log('starting queryA ' + index);
      a_query({query}).then(result => {
        console.log('finishing queryA ' + index);
        this.handleAResult(result)
      });
    });
  }

async loadDataB(){
    const { scopes, queries } = this.state;

     queries.forEach((query, qi) => {
       scopes.forEach((scope, si) => {
        console.log('starting queryB ' + qi + ':' + si);
        b_query({scope, query}).then(result => {
            console.log('finishing queryB ' + qi + ':' + si);
            this.handleBResult(result);
        });
     });
   });
 }
```

You should see ALL the `starting` logs first, A and then B ones, and then you should start seeing the `finishing` logs as they start finishing. That should verify that A and B are running "at the same time", in the sense that B requests aren't waiting for A requests to finish before B ones get started.

Comment: I've seen the edit. That means, as far as I can tell, that everything is working as expected and you have nothing to worry about.

Comment: I've read another post of yours that says the B queries take substantially longer than the A queries, so then even if B queries happen first, A queries should still finish first. Just be aware that, regardless of how you make the requests inside javascript, the javascript does not control how your server handles the requests. If your server is processing earlier requests before it begins to process later requests, then no amount of Javascript can fix that. That's a server side issue.